# Firebase PhoneAuthentication OTP not showing APP NAME correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I have the app deployed on the play store. The SHA1 and SHA256 are added in the firebase project settings. I'm using phone authentication to receive the OTP for the app. The message comes in the following format:

```
123456 is your verification code for APP_NAME.
LghSMNBa+V
```

Why is the random sting appearing? The code gets verified and it works fine but I don't want the random string to be sent along with the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I received a response from the Firebase Team. It was as follows:

> Thanks for reaching out! This is Estefani and I’ll take care of this
> case.
>
> On some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the
> incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user
> action. This uses the SMS Retriever API, which includes an 11
> character hash at the end of the SMS message. Unfortunately, it is not
> possible to change this behavior and the only thing I could do is
> submit a feature request on your behalf so this behavior can be
> removed, but even if I do there is no way to tell if it is going to be
> implemented or not and even if it gets accepted it may take time to be
> completed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be rather Google Play Services-related than it would be Firebase-related. Besides, it is unclear how you output the `String`, as no code to reproduce had been provided.

The template string can be defined in `Authentication` > `Templates` > `SMS Verification`, where the default template string is: `%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.`. No clue why it displays (likely some) ID, but one can simply split the string with `message.split(".")[0]`.
Index `[1]` may be an execution ID, which's log can be found in the GCP [Log Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query)

When it displays `APP_NAME` as a placeholder, you may first have to upload your application to Google Play Console, I'd guess at least into an internal testing track (requires a review). The scenario appears similar to in-app products not being visible unless having the app published.

For reference: https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing

Comment: So, the app is live on Google Play Store already i.e Published. In the logs That number isn't the execution ID. I'm unable to see it in the logs.